# ERROR: slist was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, list, c++14

This code isn't working for me, I am getting below-mentioned compilation errors.
Somebody please help me to point out my mistake.

```
In function 'int main()':
4:3: error: 'slist' was not declared in this scope
4:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
5:3: error: 'L' was not declared in this scope
12:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
13:3: error: 'back' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
int main() {
  slist<int> L;
  L.push_front(0);
  L.push_front(1);
  L.insert_after(L.begin(), 2);
  copy(L.begin(), L.end(),        // The output is 1 2 0
       ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
  cout << endl;

  slist<int>::iterator back = L.previous(L.end());
  back = L.insert_after(back, 3); 
  back = L.insert_after(back, 4);
  back = L.insert_after(back, 5);
  copy(L.begin(), L.end(),        // The output is 1 2 0 3 4 5
       ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <slist>`?

Comment: You should have pointed out that this is *not* your own code, you simply copied this from the STL documentation verbatim. The examples in the STL documentation are not intended to be full programs that you can copy and paste. You have to actually think about what you're doing.

Comment: FYI, the standard C++ version of `slist` is `<forward_list>`. Don't mix up STL  (an old library by SGI) with the Standard C++ library.

Answer (score 1):

All the problems boil down to the fact that the following declaration

```
slist<int> L;
```

throwed the error that

`slist` was not declared in this scope

You need to make sure `slist` is declared in your scope. `include` the necessary headers.